# Issue with `DBI::dbGetQuery` run from a Shiny app

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, r-dbi

I have a Shiny app with which the user selects a table in a SQL database and then selects some columns of this table. Then the app runs this function to get the table:

```
selectAllGetQuery <- function(conn, columns, table){
  columns <- toString(sprintf("[%s]", columns))
  query <- sprintf("select %s from %s", columns, table)
  print(columns) # ok
  print(query) # ok
  dbGetQuery(conn, query)
}
```

One table has a column named `ACT_TEMP_°C_`. When I select it, the `dbGetQuery` statement fails: **Invalid column name 'ACT_TEMP_Â°C_'**. However, as you can see, I included `print(columns)` and `print(query)` in the function, and these statements correctly print `ACT_TEMP_°C_` in the R console. So I'm really lost. The function receives the correct name but the name changes to the wrong name in `dbGetQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
dbGetQuery(conn, stringi::stri_enc_tonative(query))
```